# Binding an event handler to dynamically loaded input

Tags: javascript, jquery, live

I have a pagination input field that's dynamically created after an ajax call from the main page is made to load some data. The input field is has class `goto`.

So it's like this:
- main page has a script with a function called `loadData()`
- when a user makes an ajax call, a table is pulled from the database via ajax.
- this ajax data includes the pagination tabs (`First`,`Prev`,`Next`,`Last`), as well as the `.goto` field in which users can enter a page number. When the user enters a page number, the main page's loadData() function should be called.

This is my code (it's on the main page):

```
$('.goto').bind('keydown', function(e){
        console.log(e.which);
        if(e.which==13)
        loadData($(this).val());
    });
```

But nothing happens. Neither the console message, nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element is dynamically created, you should use the `on()` method while using [**event delegation**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind events to the element(s).

In your case, the following should work:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.goto', function(e){
    console.log(e.which);
    if(e.which==13)
    loadData($(this).val());
});
```